# To Find the most repeated word in a story using php

Tags: php

Develop a PHP document that handles the form submission on the server side. The embedded PHP scripts (in your PHP doc) first identify the "most meaningful" word in the story that has the highest number of occurrences in the submitted story text (note: a, an, the, and, etc., are not counted as meaningful words), and then responds to the user with a sentence like "Your story is regarding 'the-identified-most-meaningful-word'.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: I want the logic how to get a most repeated word in a story using php code...@ SyntaxLAMP

Comment: You can break every word into an array by exploding the string with a space as the delimiter.  Then you can use foreach() to loop through each word in the array and then use preg_match or something to find the number of occurrences

Comment: How about trying something? Not only have you simply stated that you want a solution to your (probable) course assignment, you haven't even asked any questions or ATTEMPTED to solve the problem yourself!? This is the most worthy post I've seen in a long time of the close vote for not attempting to solve the problem (which I see doesn't exist anymore... I'm doing a custom close).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the OP does not make any attempt to answer the question himself, and does not ask any specific questions about any part of the process.

Answer (score 2):

You need to break this assignment down into digestible pieces. It's not very complicated at all; I think you'll find it's fairly elementary once you see how it can be resolved to a few simple components.

You need to:

1. Iterate through a story.
2. Keep track of words you've read,
3. and the number of times you've read them,
4. but ignore a list of words.
5. Output the most common occurrence.

That's not that crazy.

First, how do you iterate through a story? Well, that depends on the language. Typically you'll find an 'explode' type function, which will break a long string into an array using a delimiter. For example, 'Hi, my name is Steve', exploded in PHP like this: `explode($string, ' ');` will transform $string into:

```
array(
  0 => 'Hi,',
  1 => 'my',
  2 => 'name',
  3 => 'is',
  4 => 'Steve',
)
```

Now you can say something like:

```
foreach ($story as $word) {
  // start counting/comparing
}
```

To keep track of all these words, you'll need an array which could be formatted one of several ways. Perhaps something like this, where the key for each word is the word itself, and its value is the number of occurrences:

```
$occurrences = array(
    'Hello,' => 1,
    'my' => 1
);
```

Then you'd need an array to list words you don't care about:

```
$ignoreWords = array(
    'and', 'a', 'the', 'etc', '...'
);
```

Now what? I don't know, something like:

```
foreach ($story as $word) {
    if (in_array($word, $ignoreWords)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (isset($occurences[$word])) {
        $occurences[$word] += 1;
    } else {
        $occurences[$word] = 1;
    }
}
```

Once the loop is completed, you just need some function to get your highest number of occurrences. You could sort the $occurrences array by value and pop the first element, or you may have a function handy like max() in PHP.

```
$highestValue = max($occurrences);
```

Then...

```
$word = array_search($highestValue, $array);
```

Then...

```
echo "The most important word in the story was {$word}.";
```

I haven't tested this code and I'm aware of several problem areas (like what happens if array_search gets multiple results), but you can probably get a sense of how this could be put together. I apologize if I've missed a finer point, but if you're asking for assignment help on SO, you need to ask better questions to get better questions. Good luck!